# Notepad++ delete until colon for every line with replace all

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm using Notepad++ Replace box to delete text to the left of the colon (:) in all 3 lines of my file:

> TRACE: do
>
> TRACE: re
>
> TRACE: mi

I'm using `^[^:]+:` in the 'Find what:' field and 'Replace with:' is empty but when it goes to the next line it automatically selects and deletes what was output in the previous line, so when I run **Replace All** it results in:

> mi

It should show:

> do
>
> re
>
> mi

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a "bug" ("feature") of Notepad++, you have to capture the rest of the line and use the value in replace:

- Find what: `^[^:]+:(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Another way is:

- Find what: `^[^:\r\n]+:`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Comment: +1. Originally, I though NP++'s implementation was fine, but I tested [this Python example](https://tio.run/##hY4xC8IwEIX3/IprlzRYXLoVixRx00XcxEptrzbYJiFJB399jBgpiOBNj3t333vqYXspMuf4qKS2oJG02IGpRzXgRaMa6gZHFDYxKajaWtSC5QT8KM39WuPSTNckWClQmoI/7Yb6Zgpv7lNo5CRskTFGyPuHlqLppQaLxuaUkR9pcRwfD@Vmm0MrSVC@W1Aj977Pqk5Vfl68EAG8k/J@xZ6L9g88munRjI@@@Ml6VUTsE@LcEw), and found that NP++ is indeed irregular by retaining position after a lookbehind is evaluated. Learn something new every day! I lack time now, but I can probably file an issue in their GitHub repo later (there's no related issue currently open).

Comment: Not to mention that it's misleading because it's inconsistent with other components of the find-and-replace tab, like what's shown to the user when previewing a change via the "Find" or "Mark". (Side note: I find "Mark" to be particularly useful when drafting regex to ensure I haven't made a silly mistake.) Really I'm starting to think I should switch text editors or start contributing my own bug fixes to Notepad++, since there are actually a surprising number of miscellaneous issues. But I guess that's probably the case for any dedicated program user like myself.

Comment: I like the second approach better -- it looks like it should work in almost any "altered implementation" of  regex interpretation.

Comment: Even shorter, by using a reluctant quantifier: Replace `^.*?:` with empty. [(Docs)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: This has to be a bug. `^[^:]*?:` and `^.*?:` should do exactly the same thing, but they don't. `^[^:\r\n]*?:` does work correctly though, so I'd guess that's where the issue is, somehow. The same issue occurs with `^.*?:` if you check the "`.` matches newline" box.

Comment: @Yay295 There is an issue, but I think the issue comes from Notepad++'s multiple-replace implementation allowing the same starting lookbehind to be evaluated multiple times (But I haven't analyzed either Notepad++'s or Python's source code, so I cannot say this with certainty). I will say that if my understanding is correct, it's not surprising that `^[^:]*?:` and `^.*?:` behave differently without dot-all mode, since that's how dot-all mode works ("dot-all mode" or "single line mode" are the common regex terms for what is activated when the "`.` matches newline" box is checked).

Comment: @Yay295 Investigating further, it seems more likely Notepad++'s multiple-replace implementation differs from the standard implementation by replacing matches one-by-one instead of pre-allocating the matches and then replacing them all (still sans source code analysis; I'm simply basing this off Boost's description of [`regex_replace`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html)). That doesn't change my earlier point about dot-all mode, but it will change the fix. Sorry if I've bored you with unnecessary technical details.